# Timer ticks with wrong values

Tags: c#, timer

I am developing a game in Windows Phone 8 SDK
and i need a countdown timer.

i implemented a Dispatcher timer , on the first time **CLICK** 
The timer decrease with no errors !

but if i press **RESET** (Which it should reset to **60 SECONDS** and start countdown)
it Resets to 60 **BUT** it Decreases "**2 Seconds**" every second !

and if i press one more time **RESET** , it Decreases by **3 Seconds** every second

> Sample code i wrote with the same idea of my app: (and same wrong
>   results)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp3.Resources;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace PhoneApp3
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private DispatcherTimer time = new DispatcherTimer(); // DISPATCHER TIMER
        private int left;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Starting Countdown
        private void Start_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            left = 60; // time left
            time.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            time.Tick += time_Tick;
            time.Start();
        }

        void time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            left--; // decrease 
            txt.Text = Convert.ToString(left);  // update text           
        }

        private void reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            time.Stop(); 
            Start_Click_1(null, null); // RE - START 
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Don't constantly add yet another Tick event handler.  Put the time.Tick assignment in the constructor.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @HansPassant i don't understand , you mean only the Tick assignment in the constructor and the rest is okay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you press reset, and `Start_Click_1` runs again, you're subscribing to `time_Tick` again:

```
time.Tick += time_Tick;
```

So after pressing Reset 3 times, you're subscribed 3 times, and the following line of code is running 3 times every time the tick event fires:

```
left--;
```

Move the subscription to your constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    time.Tick += time_Tick;
}

//Starting Countdown
private void Start_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    left = 60; // time left
    time.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    time.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Hans said in the comments, you are incorrectly adding the event handler every time the button is clicked.

You should call this code

```
time.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
time.Tick += time_Tick;
```

in the constructor, instead of the event handler.

Comment: Or, to be more exact: this results in first tick 1x executed, second tick 2x, 3rd tick 3x as every tick adds another handler to the event.